# How to retrive values of variable defined in one method into other objective c

Tags: iphone

I have a method

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {

self.locationLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude] ;
self.locationLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude ];
```

Now i want to get values of self.locationLatitude and self.locationLongitude into other method of same class But i dont want methodOne to call in locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location method

```
-(void)methodOne{
NSLog(%@,Location.Latitude);//it should show coordinate.

}
```

Other issue is where should i call methodOne? i dont want to call it in locationUpdate method. i want to call it in viewDidLoad method. but when i call it in viewDidLoad nslog shows null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the object, using self.

```
-(void)methodOne{
    NSLog(%@, self.locationLongitude);
}
```

Comment: yeah...just remove the square brackets and put %@ in quotes as : ("%@",self.locationLongitude)

Comment: This is a little off, but in the right direction as tipycalFlow pointed out. Can be `self.locationLongitude` or `[self locationLongitude]`

Comment: Actaully my methodone gets called in viewDidLoad method. so it shows null by above method

Comment: calling methodOne in viewDidLoad will always return a <null> result now.  At the time the view is loaded, the location is not yet found, so it logs self.locationLatitude at that time, which is still <null>.  This method should instead be called after the location is determined.

Comment: @superjessi u r absolutely right. but problem is i process data in method one. and shows data into table view. now whenever it gets location it process all data and make system busy which i dont want. i want to process data when view loads.